# Spring Custom User Details from DAL - Casting

Tags: java, spring, casting, data-access-layer

I'm currently working on a System that makes use of Spring Security. I have the Authentication Provider setup but I'm having a problem creating a custom User Type which would store all the information I need.

In the Authentication Provider, I call a "User Service" which is a DAL to the users in the system. This then returns a "User" object. Which is fine and that's all working.

But I then have a MyCompanyUserDetails object defined which contains all the custom attributes I need. This Class extends the "User" class.

My Problem is I can't cast the User to CompanyUserDetails. Am I missing something here ?

The Custom User Details Type:

```
public class MyCompanyUserDetails extends User {
```

and in my Authentication Provider:

```
// Create / Update the user.
User raw_user_details = getUser(username_str, groups_of_user);

// Create our Custom user object filled with the parameters we need for the rest of the system.
MyCompanyUserDetails details = (MyCompanyUserDetails) raw_user_details;
```

The exception I receive:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: User cannot be cast to MyCompanyUserDetails
```

Any help / guidance would be appreciated...

Comment: any error or exception that you can provide?

Comment: Which class is this `MyCompanyUserDetails`? You have mentioned `CompanyUserDetails` class that extends `User`. If `MyCompanyUserDetails` also extends class `User` then you are trying to downcast the instance variable, which I think is not possible, which is why you must be getting that exception

Comment: My apologies they are the same class.

Comment: then it must be the downcasting problem

Comment: I guess you need to implement your own UserDetailsService in a way that the loadUserByUsername method returns an instance of MyCompanyUserDetails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a simple DownCasting Problem as Stated by Shades88 in the Comments